How to solve: Found unconstructed IntlDateFormatter while building Form in Symfony?
I creating a Symfony 6 form:
->add('startAt', DateType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'required' => false,
])

I have an error, saying:
Found unconstructed IntlDateFormatter
I expecting form, without errors, i used forms, especially DateTypes a lot of times before

Did you check php_intl extension, if it is activated.

Nope it's not that.. I also have php8.2-intl installed and the extension is enabled. I'm seeing the same error. An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Found unconstructed IntlDateFormatter")
